# Systemd: How to start/stop services on battery

Tags: systemd

Is there a way to use systemd to start/stop services when a laptop is on battery or logged in?

As a developer it's helpful to have things like mongodb and redis autostart, but I would like to suspend them when on battery to save as much as possible.

Comment: The version of systemd in Ubuntu 15.04 has a condition named `ConditionACPower` that you can use to determine if a service should start. However, this condition is checked only when starting the service, so if the AC power is disconnected after the service is started, then the service will still continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great article about this here: https://chrisdown.name/2017/10/29/adding-power-related-targets-to-systemd.html

**Option 1**

Basically you have to do following:

Create `systemd` target for AC power enabled:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/system/ac.target << 'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=On AC power
DefaultDependencies=no
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
EOF
```

Create `systemd` target for running on battery power:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/system/battery.target << 'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=On battery power
DefaultDependencies=no
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
EOF
```

Reboot the system or simply run `systemctl daemon-reload` to load these new configuration files.

Add `udev` rules to trigger state changes:

```
cat > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-powertargets.rules << 'EOF'
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", KERNEL=="AC", ATTR{online}=="0", RUN+="/usr/sbin/systemctl start battery.target"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", KERNEL=="AC", ATTR{online}=="1", RUN+="/usr/sbin/systemctl start ac.target"
EOF
```

Now reboot the system or just run `udevadm control --reload-rules` to activate the newly added `udev` configuration file.

After this you can query the current system state with

```
$ sudo systemctl status battery.target
● battery.target - On battery power
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/battery.target; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 29 12:24:33 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Reached target On battery power.
Oct 29 12:24:33 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: battery.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Oct 29 12:24:33 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Stopped target On battery power.
```

You can then create new `systemd` service scripts that use these new states. For example

```
$ systemctl cat powerdown.service
# /etc/systemd/system/powerdown.service
[Unit]
Description=Laptop battery savings

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/powerdown

[Install]
WantedBy=battery.target
```

**Option 2**

If you don't really want to play with all the `systemd` complexity, you can use just the `udev` part and directly run scripts on that.

```
cat > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-my-battery-commands.rules << 'EOF'
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", KERNEL=="AC", ATTR{online}=="0", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/script-to-run-when-losing-ac-power"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", KERNEL=="AC", ATTR{online}=="1", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/script-to-run-when-ac-power-restored"
EOF
```

and use `udevadm control --reload-rules` (and `udevadm trigger` seems to work, too) to load the new config.

If you want to know in the middle of some shell script if AC power is currently available, just run `on_ac_power`. It silently returns true exit code if AC power is connected, or false if running on battery. Be warned though that `on_ac_power` is too stupid to return true if running in system without a batter (e.g. desktop system).

Comment: This is a neat approach, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert on systemd, but I google better than the average bear. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management:

> There is just one thing systemd cannot do (as of systemd-204): power management depending on whether the system is running on AC or battery. To fill this gap, you can create a single udev rule that runs a script when the AC adapter is plugged and unplugged:

Further instructions follow.

My guess is you want to do something like create a fake service called `acpluggedin.service` which is started and stopped by the udev rule, and then have the mongo and redis services `Requires` it. Or something.

Comment: Thanks! I had found that page but missed that comment. It's a strange limitation (and people say that systemd does too much). Marking as accepted answer, and hoping in the future something better comes along.